# IOS NSURLRequest under a Webview Ajax application timeout settings

Tags: iphone, ajax, ios7, webview, nsurlrequest

I am working on an IOS application. It launches a `WebView` and loads an HTML page under that using `NSURLRequest`. Once the initial page is loaded, different html links on that page will be traversed to fetch different information. All works well when HTML links respond within 10 seconds, but http requests are terminated/timeout when the response time is more than 10 seconds. I am not sure, what exactly times out. Is it the `NSURLRequest`/`WebView`/ etc. I don't set any timeout value for the initial `NSURLRequest`. Note that the slow requests(>10 sec response time) works well in a normal web browser, so there is no server side logic that terminates/times out the request.

I have implemented the `UIWebViewDelegate` in my IOS code and I see the following function called even for the timed out requests:

```
(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

On the server side, the request keep processing and finally finishes successfully but IOS webView is already finished loading the page so does not display the result.

I am trying to figure out any `timeout` settings related to `NSURLRequest`/`WebView`/ etc.

Answer (score 0):

To increase timeout delay to 30 seconds on a NSURLRequest I use following constructor:

`NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:30];`

Comment: Sorry mate this does not work. I believe this works only for the first NSURLRequest, which i make in my application. But for following html links traversal it does not. I may be wrong but I have already tested using the same constructor. No luck :-(